# How to add new tab in CMS desk in kentico cms

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

How can I add new tab in **CMSDesk** -> **content** -> **Page**
position is showing in below image in red section.

[image]

I was trying to add this by adding new element in Development -> Modules -> user interface section.
but not getting module name for this section.

Any help is appreciate.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will presume you are using Kentico CMS v7. (The situation is different in v6.)

If I understand it correctly you want to add one more level of tabs UNDER Page tab. It is possible although I strongly don't recommend it. I would rather add a tab NEXT to Page, Design etc. by simply adding UI element CMSSitemanager->Development->Modules->Content->User Interface->Content->View mode->Edit. But if you want answer to you question I will provide you with it :) You will need to customize logic in

```
 CMSDeskPage.GetDocumentPageUrlInternal(...)
```

The code file is located at CMSSolution\UIControls\Pages\CMSDesk\CMSDeskPage.cs

There is a switch with case "edit" - this is the place determining which page will be displayed under the Page tab. You will have to create one more layer of pages (frameset with tabs and content). You will also have to create JavaScript layer to ensure proper communication between frames. (Scripts I'm talking about are: tree.js, contenteditframeset.js, content.js, splitview.js).

Once again - use the UI Elements version mentioned above :)

Comment: yeah use of UI element version is better.Thanks for your help.